# Should I use "made of" or "made from"?

Tags: word-choice

> "The toy train is made of plastic."

Or

> "The toy train is made from plastic."

Which one is correct? Why?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate. The original may have been worded quite differently, though.

Comment: Both are correct and grammatical. There's a slight (significant in some context) difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Either is acceptable but this one is more common: "The toy train is made of plastic" - because the plastic still exists in the same state.  As opposed to, for example, steel, which is made *from* iron and other metals.   Or ice, made from water.  Whereas one would say that an ice sculpture is made of ice.

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence would be "The toy train is made of plastic." This is because the train is made up of plastic, it is a plastic train.

As mentioned in another reply, if an object is made from another material into an entirely new object (e.g. "steel is made from iron"), then you would use "made from."

Comment: As with Kanan's answer, any sources to substantiate this?

Answer (score -1):

We often use `made from` when we talk about how something is manufactured, it means form is changed during the process of making.if something keeps it form then `made of` is used.
The toy train is made of plastic is correct..

Comment: Can you cite some sources, please?

Comment: @Kris 'made from' means when something is manufactured and made of means when something is 'composed of'.